# Running into Typescript error when trying to pull state out of History object with an enum property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an enum that looks something like,

```
enum values {
  first,
  second,
}
```

And in my component, I access the history object as,

```
const { push, location: { state = {} } } = useHistory();
```

In that same component, in a `useEffect`, I do something like,

```
const { first } = values;
useEffect(() => {
  if (!state[first]) {
    // do something
  }
}, []);
```

This throws the error,

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 
'values.first' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property '[values.first]' does not exist on type '{}'.ts
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I supposed to write my own interface for `state`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here,

```
const { push, location: { state = {} } } = useHistory();
                                  ^
```

Because you destructure with the default value of state being an empty object(`{}`). TS will infer the key and value as `any`.

The solution is to provide an explicit type for the `LocationState` by passing a generic type argument to `useHistory` call. For the enum you are working with the type may look something like this,

```js
enum values {
  first,
  second,
}

type TLocState = { [key in values]: string /* desired type for value */ }

const { push, location: { state } } = useHistory<TLocState>();

// someVal will be infered as string
const someVal = state[values.first]
```

Have a look at the [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAbghgGzMAzlA3gKCjqAzASwCcUAXAGm1wTjMwF9NMBjAexDKjLlOCgF4MjTAHoRsRFAAWtKHBBQCEAA4ICzAqTkgAnlFI7lwTAmBb4CAV1I9gAbQvIUAOkIlSAXWwmz12wDECAA8ALgwoOwBrYD0CBUdUDzCyIjiAcyh6K3QABjCAIilgBARWfPIoAEYCgCMdYHzhU3NEQKCrbl42h0QnV2IyLyA)

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped.